# Find the coordinates of the point

Tags: calculus

Find the coordinates of the point on the curve $y=x^3$ where $x≥0$, closest to the point $(0,4)$.

$d^2(x)$ = $x^2$ + $(x^3-4)$$^2$= $m(x)$

no way to calculate $m'(x)=0$

Shall I calculate $d^2(x)$? And then derieve and make it equal to $0$? When I do so, I do not get the roots. How can this be solved?

Comment: Your approach seems right, could you provide more of your work so that we can find where the error might be?

Comment: So what can be done now?

Comment: Why is there no way to calculate $m'(x)=0$?

Comment: How can this be calculated $x^2+x^6-8x^3+16=0$ ?

Comment: Of the derivative, $x=0$ is a root, there are two positive roots, and the other two roots are complex.

Comment: But is the way to solve this correct?

Comment: @SamWeatherhog The expression above is for $m(x)=0$, where it should be $m'(x)=0$.  This will remove the constant term.

Comment: There's no constant term on the end. $m'(x)=2x+2(x^3-4)\cdot 3x^2=2x(3x^4-12x+1)$. So $x=0$ is a root and then you need to solve the quartic.

Comment: Yes your method is correct. If you can minimize/maximize $d^2$ then you will have minimised/maximised $d$. So it's always easier to work with $d^2$ rather than introducing square roots.

Comment: @SamWeatherhog Check the sign on your expression, you need $x^3-4$.

Comment: Ah thanks @MichaelBurr, I should've checked that!

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan, I am interested to know the x-coordinate of your solution is it: 1.588 or 1.603 or may be neither? Please update the question once you found the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance $A=(x,y)$ to $P=(0,4)$:
$$
d^2(x,y) = x^2 + (y - 4)^2
$$
We take $A$ from the graph of 
$$
y = x^3 \quad (x \ge 0)
$$
using parametrization $(t, t^3)$ then
$$
q(t) = d^2(t) = t^2 + (t^3-4)^2
$$
Looking for local extrema:
$$
\dot{q}(t) = 2t + 2(t^3-4)3t^2
$$
then for $t\ne 0$:
$$
0 = 1 + 3(t^3-4)t \iff \\
0 = t^4 - 4t + 1/3 \quad (*)
$$
My friend Maxima told me this quartic $(*)$ has two real and two complex solutions, and the real solution for the minimum of $q(t)$ is:
\begin{align}
t &= {{\sqrt{9\,\left({{16\,\sqrt{182}}\over{27}}+8
 \right)^{{{2}\over{3}}}+4}}\over{6\,\left({{16\,\sqrt{182}}\over{27
 }}+8\right)^{{{1}\over{6}}}}}+{{\sqrt{-\left({{16\,\sqrt{182}}\over{
 27}}+8\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}+{{24\,\left({{16\,\sqrt{182}}\over{27
 }}+8\right)^{{{1}\over{6}}}}\over{\sqrt{9\,\left({{16\,\sqrt{182}
 }\over{27}}+8\right)^{{{2}\over{3}}}+4}}}-{{4}\over{9\,\left({{16\,
 \sqrt{182}}\over{27}}+8\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}}}}}\over{2}}
\\
&= 1.558590043156065\cdots
\end{align}
This gives the solution 
$$
A=(1.558590043156065\cdots,3.786131488009289\cdots)
$$

[image: the situation]